# Finding a common pattern from input lines using single command

Tags: shell, unix

I have below two lines. I want only part of line which has .script & after / using single command.

Input lines

```
hello/world/command_altr.program_for_input.script   
hello/world/script/deleted_the_input.program_for_output.script
/com/bash/hastag/welcome/program -u util/basic/level/learning
```

Output expected :

```
command_altr.program_for_input.script 

deleted_the_input.program_for_output.script
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `sed`?

Comment: Yes, using sed or AWK I can get for only one line. I should be able to take common pattern from n input lines. Need ur assistance

Comment: Sed works on multiple lines. `sed 's|.*/\(.*script\).*|\1|'` might be good enough, but your problem is underspecified.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It works

Comment: can u plz explain me

Comment: How much of it do you understand? Do you know how to write a substitution command in sed?

Comment: Not perfectly, but I'm learning. can u help me out !

Comment: If you won't tell me how much of it you understand, then you are asking me to teach you sed, which is not what this site i for. I advise you to read some online sed tutorials and work through the examples.

Comment: I understood ur answer but can it be done with AWK ? (as I feel easy with that)

Comment: What have you tried in awk?

Comment: Yes; but i m not gettig the desired  output with second input. For first input, im getting the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I properly understand your problem, this can be solved with sed.

```
sed -n -r -e 's/^.*\/([^/]+\.script).*$/\1/p'
```

It will extract the given pattern and and print it. Lines without the pattern are discarded.

`^.*\/` searches a string starting beginning of a line, containing any char and ended by a /

`([^/]+\.script)` searches a repetition of one or several chars (except /), followed by a dot and the string "script". If found, it is put in a remembered pattern thanks to the `(....)`

`.*$` searches any number of chars up to end_of_line

`/\1/` replaces the line by the remembered pattern.

'p' prints if pattern has been found.

Comment: Thank you, can u please tell me where I can execute steps (any online terminal or offline terminals or anywhere so that I can try your answer).

Comment: You can try that  http://tpcg.io/5dx89b You just have to paste you input lines in the stdin tab.

Comment: Can u plz explain me the answer

Comment: I added some details in the answer.

Comment: Thanks Alian for details. Can u xplain me what is the use for -r ?

Comment: -r slightly changes the regexp syntax. Without it, '(' should be '\\(', '+' (one or more repetition of a pattern) does not exists, etc...

Comment: Im not getting output when i tried to put pipe with my input statement .                                                  Input statement | above sed command

Comment: It is probably because your input statement does not end. Are you sure it is not interactive and expects inputs by the user. This is what happens most of the times. Try 'cat the-file-with-the patterns' | sed ... and it works.

Comment: My script is something like this. variable =  x | grep statement (till here it gives me the input lines mentioned in my qstn)  | sed (statement as u suggested).          yes, the inputs are expected by the user which is x.  Adding to above, im copying all the output in variable. I tried , its not wrkng for me !! Need ur help

Comment: Put your data in a file. There is no reason to use a variable. To use a var, you should first set your var `var=x` (no space around =). Then `echo $var |  grep ... | sed ...`But using a file is much simpler.  Put your text in a file (with cat, an editor, ...). Then `< file | grep .... | sed ...`

Comment: Thanku Alain for ur inputs. It resolved  my issue & gave the required output.